# Letting a user know about an illegal input to a function

Tags: java, c++, error-handling

This is kind of a broad question but I wanted to ask anyways. Hopefully I won't get a lot of down votes :)

Today I have been to an interview and (as usual) they asked me to write a function that calculates the factorial of a number. After that we discussed a little bit about what can crash the program and talked about how to let a user know when a negative value is being passed to the function.

I personally said using assertions or maybe returning a special number to let the user know but I am not sure if he was very happy with these answers.

In your opinion, what is a good way to let a user know about an illegal value being passed to a function or what is the best thing to do in such a situation?

Comment: Exceptions vs. success/error return values, classic debate.

Comment: Imo: Never use assertions in the public part of your library. Those are there to catch your own programming errors, not to validate input. Also since most people use the release version of libraries, they'll never even see the assertion being thrown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### I heard u lajk exceptions?

The C++ way of things is to throw an exception, this will force the user of your code to explicitly do something if something goes wrong - otherwise his/hers application will terminate.

This is also the broad recommendation<sup>1</sup> when it comes to error-handling, and the arguments regarding the performance impact of using *exceptions* has started to fade off as computer power increases and compilers get smarter.

Some claim that using exceptions breaks the readability of your code, that it will make it hard to follow and hard to maintain, and there might be some truth in that.

Throwing an exception and cleaning up is far from an easy task in more advanced situations, though in a function responsible for calculating something as *"simple"* as a factorial of a number - using exceptions is quite an easy task.

---

The biggest problem with C++ exceptions (from my point of view) is the lack of a `finally`-clause, if it would be possible to use one then writing the code responsible for clean-up after an exception have been caught would be a much more simple task.

---

Recommended read:

- **[http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq - [17] Exceptions and error handling](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/exceptions.html)**

---

<sup>**footnotes:**</sup>
<sup><sup>1.</sup> subjective opinion, of course.</sup>

---

#### Consistency throughout your project..

If you find a good method of letting callers of your code know that something went wrong (could be through a *return-value*, an error flag set by reference or a *exception*, or pretty much.. anything) just make sure that you use the same *error-notification-system* throughout the whole project.

Nothing is more annoying than when you use a lib with inconstancy in regards to error-handling.

Comment: The lack of `finally` is more than made up for by deterministic object destruction. Just make sure that anything that needs cleaning up is managed by an RAII object.

Answer (score 2):

My first choice would be an exception, because it forces the user of the function to treat that error. If you returned a special value, the user could ignore it and just go on with the special error value, which will result in wrong results.

Answer (score 2):

It is always a good idea to validate your inputs, this is just good coding practice.

Letting your user know is an interesting question, and heavily dependent on your implementation.  If you are building a GUI based program, you can always validate the input prior to it being inserted to your routine.  If the input is invalid, then you can always show an indicator on screen.

If you are simply providing nothing more than an API, then I would argue that throwing exceptions is probably the best way.  I have seen implementations of functions LIKE factorial where the answer is provided back as the return, and a separate input parameter is provided as lets say an unsigned int * that the user provides so that a second return value can be provided as a status, where the integer provided back represents an error code of sorts.

As I write most of my own WHOLE PROGRAMS, I am a big fan of pre-validating inputs coming from the interface prior to putting the routine that will truly process the inputs, and providing an output on the GUI if the input is invalid!

Answer (score 2):

I would throw an Exception - more probably a Checked Exception (in Java).

See: [Advantages of Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/advantages.html) - Advantage #2: Propagating error up the call stack sort of fall in line with what being asked "how to let the user know" - well the user started the call, so eventually the exception is returned all the way up.

More specifically, you'll want to use Checked Exception:
A quick search for some info: [Checked vs Unchecked Exception](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129)

> Checked exceptions : represent invalid conditions in areas outside the
>   immediate control of the program (***invalid user input***, da tabase problems, network outages, absent files)

as opposed to Unchecked Exception which usually to represent a failure in your code logic / implementation

Comment: I believe that comment is refering to "user input" as input from a keyboard user, not necessarily a library user.  Two classic examples from java are NullPointerException and IllegalArgumentException, both of which are unchecked.

Comment: Yes it is - and I assumed that was the context of "user input" in the question.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what the function is, and how it's used.
You could have a special return value, throw an exception, or set an error flag depending on your needs. I think the important thing is to have a reasonable project-wide philosophy with regard to this, and use it consistently.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to notify an end-user that he has made an incorrect input to your application then you should display a dialog to that states that this is the case.

If, however, you are talking about someone else implementing your code, then [refp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11530126/1489700) is best.